# Running parallel job in a linux cluster - mpich error

Tags: ubuntu, cluster

First of all I would like to say it is my first message here and I'm not sure this the right place, I guess it us but... If it fits better in another stackexchange site please let me know.

It's three months ago I'm in charge of a cluster with six computers (Suse Linux 9.2) running a meteorological model in forecast mode. Recently because of a cut in the power supply one of the nodes crashed. After installing Lubuntu 12.04 (Suse 9.2 disks were not available, only 10.2) I tried to reconnect this computer to the cluster:

1. Installed openssh server
2. Run ssh-keygen to ssh without requiring password
3. Installed NFS support
4. Edited /etc/fstab
5. Edited /etc/hosts

Then I tried to run the met model but got this error message:

> rm_1993:  p4_error: Could not gethostbyname for host thalassa; may be invalid name : 61
>   p0_12316:  p4_error: Child process exited while making connection to remote process on thalassa3: 0

After Google searching I found some issues about /etc/resolv.conf and then edited this file:

> domain ceam.es
>   dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1
>   nameserver 127.0.0.1

But the error message still appears. I assume I'm missing something, I am not an expert sysadmin but I have to deal with.

You can find [error log](http://ubuntuone.com/0HlGLscuW27t2ECaWbimtM), [hosts](http://ubuntuone.com/4GxhYMLrXoocYEQb4gSXHh) and [resolv.conf](http://ubuntuone.com/3JVv7jKOMYZ1NPiThVr3JA) here.

Any help or idea will be greatly appreciated, I'll go on searching over the net for a solution.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you may need to remove this line from /etc/hosts:

> 127.0.1.1 thalassa3

because this way you get 2 IPs for a single hostname which /etc/hosts can't handle.

Then, having all the needed information in /etc/hosts, I'd rather blank /etc/resolv.conf to avoid ambiguity.

Regarding `dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1` in /etc/resolv.conf.
As you can see in the comment at the beginning of file:

> ```
> # Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)  
> #     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
> ```

you are not expected to edit this file by hand. According to the new rules `dns-nameservers` should be specified in /etc/network/interfaces, which will automatically propagate changes to /etc/resolv.conf (assuming you have resolvconf package installed). That is as per a server edition of Ubuntu OS. If you are by some reason using an installation with gui, you probably have to make these changes through Network Manager.

You might also want to check the contents of /etc/hostname to verify it is correct. If you edit it, you'll have to reboot to make changes persistent.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Pavel  I'll remove the line from /etc/hosts. I don't edit resolv.conf by hand. I go to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d and edit "head". If needed, which changes are to be made in /etc/network/interfaces  Content of /etc/hostname is a single line: thalassa3

Comment: @pacomet, editing /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head is not a very good idea. It is expected that resolvconf gathers this information from various sources including /etc/network/interfaces. Just add the dns-nameservers to the description of an interface. It should look something like this: `auto eth1  iface eth1 inet static  address 192.168.1.3  ...  dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1`. If you absolutely need to explicitly add something to /etc/resolv.conf you should write that to /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base, which is intended for that.

Comment: B/w, do you use the dns server at 192.168.1.1 to resolv the addresses of cluster nodes or just for the outer world? And one more point - you may have to change node name in /etc/hostname to `thalassa3.ceam.es`. Have you looked at how these files look on other cluster nodes?

Comment: Thanks @Pavel ¡¡It's working now!! I restored the original head to resolv.conf and checked the content of /etc/network/interfaces in another cluster with Ubuntu. Now it is working fine. I'll add the file to the question so it could help other users. Regarding the dns server I just want to resolve the cluster nodes in thalassa3, only the central node connects to the outer world.

Comment: Glad, you have solved the problem. Just some more comments: 1. It looks little strange to me that you don't have `auto eth0` just before the `iface eth0 inet static` line. The `auto eth0` directive would allow the interface to be brought up at boot; 2. regarding the DNS server. In such case there is no need to specify DNS server settings on cluster nodes at all - you have all the required bindings set up in /etc/hosts. 3. If you don't mind, I'd ask you to post the final versions of these files: */etc/hosts*, */etc/hostname* and */etc/network/interfaces*, so that we know how a working ..

Comment: .. configuration looks like. And the final comment - so the source of the problem was that interfaces `eth0` was not configured in /etc/network/interfaces on thalassa3, right?

Comment: Well, maybe I run too fast. At least model tests are run. I have to wait some hours to check if the model properly runs. I'll post the files tomorrow after finishing today test

Comment: I have tried running a short model exercise and got the same error again. I'm sorry I was confused about the node up and running. I'll go on testing and say something, thank you very much in any case.

Comment: Hi, @pacomet. So, how is it going?

Comment: Hi @Pavel On Friday I was so lost I had to reinstall LUbuntu again. Today I have setup ssh.jeygen and NFS again. I've noticed gcc is not installed in thalassa3, should I install? I assume I have to do it

Comment: If I run tstmachines from mpich on thalassa (central node) everything seems to run, no errors are reported. Thaks for your interest and help

Comment: Hi @Pavel it seems that adding info to /etc/network/interfaces is not the solution. You can take a look at http://ubuntuone.com/60d3TVXqY2TBkEe0BPSguw  Though, I have rebooted thalassa3 and now it is not available from central node, ping is not responding. It seems it has problems to mount NFS so it is taking very long time to reboot. Maybe I'll need to reinstall ubuntu again. I'm out of the office this week so it will take long time to solve.

Comment: @pacomet. Make sure eth0 is up after you boot thalassa3 - have a look at the output of `ip addr`. It seems to me that it should be down after boot without `iface eth0 inet static` line in /etc/network/interfaces - see my comment on Jan 31. NFS and any other network filesystems timing out during boot indicate that as well.

Comment: Thanks @Pavel As I'm out of the office this week I'll try your suggestion next monday and let you know. Thanks for your help and patience

Comment: @pacomet, I'm just doing some clustering myself, so it's kind of interesting to get other people going with this.